# I am modifying a copy of a queue, not the queue itself. I don't know where the copy is made

Tags: c++, arduino

This is c++ code running under Arduino.
In the following the ArenaGrid class is instantiated as arenaGrid. The sendTiles looks for tiles that haven't been sent to a vehicle. Finding one it marks the tile through changeNotified. The problem is that it seems to mark a copy, not the original.

tile.seenChanges_.size() reports 1
arenaGrid.grid_.tiles_.front().seenChanges_.size() reports 0

```
struct Vehicle
{
   int id;
}
struct Tile
{
   std::vector<int> seenChanges_;
   void changeNotified(int id){
     seenChanges_.push_back(id);
   }
}

struct Grid
{
  std::vector<Tile> tiles_;
};

class ArenaGrid
{
  public:
  std::vector<Vehicle> &getVehicles(){
    return vehicles_;
  }
  std::vector<Point> &getTiles(){
    return grid_.tiles_;
  }
  Grid grid_;
  std::vector<Vehicle> vehicles_;
}
.....

void sendTiles(){
  std::vector<Tile> tiles = arenaGrid.getTiles();
  std::vector<Vehicle> vehicles = arenaGrid.getVehicles();
  for (auto &tile : tiles){
    bool found = false;
    for (auto &vehicle : vehicles)
    {
      for (auto &v : tile.seenChanges_)
      {
        if (v == vehicle.id)
        {
          found = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!found)
      {
        tile.changeNotified(vehicle.id);
        Serial.printf("After return: %u entries\n\n", tile.seenChanges_.size());
        Serial.printf("After return2: %u entries\n\n", arenaGrid.grid_.tiles_.front().seenChanges_.size());
        .....
        return;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: A copy is made when you pass by value.  No copies are made when you pass by reference or by pointer.  The usual coding guidelines are to pass by reference or constant reference if the parameter is not modified.  Data types that can fit into a processor's register don't need to be passed by reference unless they intend to be modified.

Comment: `std::vector<Tile> tiles = arenaGrid.getTiles();` Thats a copy. `std::vector<Vehicle> vehicles = arenaGrid.getVehicles();` and another copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suspected theory as to what's happening is correct.

```
std::vector<Tile> tiles = arenaGrid.getTiles();
```

`getTiles()` returns a reference to a vector of `Tile`s. The referenced vector gets copied into `tiles`. That's where the copy is made. This should be changed to:

```
std::vector<Tile> &tiles = arenaGrid.getTiles();
```

or, even

```
auto &tiles = arenaGrid.getTiles();
```

Note that another copy is made here:

```
std::vector<Vehicle> vehicles = arenaGrid.getVehicles();
```

This does not appear to be material, but it's still a useless copy.